# ExpandableListView with non repeating element in sub group

Tags: android, spinner, expandablelistview

[image: I am working on an android application. In this application I am using an ExpandableListView in which I want to add a spinner in the child element which would be non repeating and would be placed at the top inside it. Is that possible? Or is there some other widget which I need to use to achieve this functioanlity.]

To be more preicse, this is what I mean

What I want to implement is that I need to expand a list view with options on the click of the list view group. On expanding the view, the user is to be presented with a group of options, plus there would be a drop down based on which these group of values can be edited or viewed. So this is a single drop down(meaning non repetitive) unlike all other items in a list view, and the remaining options are similar to list view items. I hope I am clear this time

Comment: ??? Very unclear. What do you mean with non repeating? And what kind of functionality do you want to implement?

Comment: Hello GreenApps, What I mean is , actually what I want to implement is that I need to expand a list view with options on the click of the list view group. On expanding the view, the user is to be presented with a group of options, plus there would be a drop down based on which these group of values can be edited or viewed. So this is a single drop down(meaning non repetitive) unlike all other items in a list view, and the remaining options are similar to list view items. I hope I am clear this time

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand what you want. An expandable listview has only group headers and child items. You are not even referring to them. Please start with them.

Comment: Check the image in question

Comment: What should i see? Unless you post a sequence of images which illustrate what you want this all stays unclear to me.